# Merge one dict into another of the same structure but containing None values

Tags: python

If I have
`dict1 = {"a": 0.0, "b": None}` and `dict2 = {"a": None, "b": 2.2}`, how can I do a righthand merge from dict1 to dict2 where the value for the key get's replaced **ONLY if it is NOT NONE**

Desired result: `{"a": 0.0, "b": 2.2}`.

If `dict1 = {"a": 0.0, "b": 5.5}` and `dict2 = {"a": None, "b": 2.2}`, desired result: `{"a": 0.0, "b": 5.5}`

Comment: Do you know how to loop over the keys/values in a dict?  Do you know how to check if a value is None?

Answer (score 0):

This will not add items with the value of `None` from `dict1`, but won't remove items with the value of `None` from `dict2` that are not updated from `dict1`.

```
dict1 = {"a": 0.0, "b": None}
dict2 = {"a": None, "b": 2.2}

# use a dictionary comprehension to skip any elements of dict1 that are None
dict2.update({ k:v for k,v in dict1.items() if not v is None })

# or
dict2 |= { k:v for k,v in dict1.items() if not v is None}

# refrain from adding items from dict1 that aren't already in dict2
dict2 |= { k:v for k,v in dict1.items() if not v is None and k in dict2}

print(dict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dict.update` and dictionary comprehension to accomplish this:

```py
dict1 = {"a": 0.0, "b": None}
dict2 = {"a": None, "b": 2.2}

result = {}
for d in [dict2, dict1]:
    result.update({k: v for k, v in d.items() if v is not None})
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'b': 2.2, 'a': 0.0}
```

- The dictionary comprehension picks those items whose value is not `None`.
- This method works for more than one dictionaries.